# "the length of time ago that it has taken light to travel from him to me"

Tags: sentence-construction

> If I look at a person in the same room as myself I see him not as he
> is “now” but as he was at some point in the past—namely the length of
> time ago that it has taken light to travel from him to me. In our
> ordinary lives the distances involved, and therefore the
> time-intervals, are so minuscule that we ignore them

[Ultimate Questions, Bryan Magee]

Does "the length of time ago that it has taken light to travel from him to me" mean that "the length of time ago that light has needed to travel from him to me?

Comment: yes indeed, that is what it means

Comment: @Esther: anyway, what is the role of the word "involved" in the context? Is it necessary?

Comment: It's the distances involved in light traveling that far. (In fact, it takes far longer for human eyes and nerves to form an image of a person than it does for light to travel across a room).